# Is it correct to say "I Could have called you and informed you?" or "I Could have called you and could have informed you"?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say

> I could have called you and informed you

or

> I could have called you and could have informed you

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical. You'd only use the second, where **could** is repeated, if you're wishing to stress  that past capability.

> I could have called you and could have informed you, if you had had your phone with you. So stop blaming me for the snafu!
>
> You're right. I could have called you and could have informed you. I dropped the ball. I'm sorry about that.